# Redirect page with GET-Parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I was trying to redirect a specific page with unpredictable GET-Params

```
http://example.com/colours/hex.php?h=210&s=100&v=80...
```

to another page which shall receive the GET-Params

```
https://newsite.com/colorful/hexadecimal.php?h=210&s=100&v=80...
```

My try looked like this:

```
Redirect /colours/hex.php https://newsite.com/colorful/hexadecimal.php
```

But this only worked when no GET-Parameters were specified. It seems like the Server doesn't recognize the page otherwise, how do I make it noticing the GET-Parameters?

I am not very experienced with this so you may help me understanding the following, too:
The .htaccess shall be placed within the colours folder at example.com .
But the paths within the htaccess refer to the root-folder of the Domain,
so I have to add /colours/ before hex.php, otherwise it doesn't work. Why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using mod_rewrite instead, you'll need to make sure mod_rewrite is loaded (otherwise the rules will cause a 500 server error). So in the htaccess file in the **example.com** document root, add these rules to it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^colours/hex\.php$ https://newsite.com/colorful/hexadecimal.php [L,QSA,R]
```

You can change the `R` to a `R=301` to make the redirect permanent. The query string should automatically get appended to the new URL.